# Custom Chart in SSRS Report

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, dynamics-crm, mschart

I am currently working on a peiece of report which has a graph/chart. The interval of X-axis needs to be increasing. That means we need to have dynamic intervals. I am just wondering whether there is a solution to it. The report needs to be ran at dynamic CRM, so it needs to be a SSRS report. I feel like it is quite a big challenge for me and I think it is beyond my knowledge. Is it achievable?  I knew there is custom code section in the report that I can use. Can I draw charts using visual basic, then print it out in the report?

As I am new here, I won't be able to
Thank you very much

Answer (score 0):

I may be missing something, but this is pretty easy: create your chart, and then right click on the X axis labels and select "Horizontal Axis Properties..." In the resulting dialog you can specify the "Interval" Click on the function button ("fx") and you can enter a formula using data from your datasets or parameters.

A valid formula might be:

```
=IIF(Parameters!View.Value = "By Day", 24 , 168)
```

On rereading your question, I think you might be asking if the groupings of data can be dynamic. Yes, certainly, but I think I would probably do that in the query, with appropriate SQL aggregates.

Comment: Thanks, but according the client, the interval value need to be 55+5*pow(counter,1.85) where counter =gridline counter. Not just like jumping between 2 values.

Comment: OK. I think I get it. A single chart needs to have a varying interval along the axis, but not logarithmic. I'll experiment with this in a few hours, but I don't think there's an option to support this in SSRS.

Answer (score 0):

I had to use custom assembly to draw the whole graph/chart in the end. Thanks